# Dropbox and Android - get Files names via API call

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Does anyone know how to get metadata list...I mean Files and Folder which exist in our app folder in dropbox in Android.i need to get File and Folder names..
Now again i want to create Folder in Dropbox from android.i reffered dropbox docs.but didn't find same in that..
Thanx in advance.

Comment: check this: http://code.google.com/p/dropdowner/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here what i have done and it works fine for me.

`SavedProperties.selectedAddress` is my `static` variable which contains name of folder to be created.

Here i am

1) checking whether folder exists.

2) create folder if does not exist.

3) upload files to that folder.

```
    private void loadMetadata() 
    {


        // Metadata
        try 
        {
            Entry existingEntry = mApi.metadata("/" + SavedProperties.selectedAddress , 1, null, false, null);
            if(existingEntry.isDir)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Folder exists : " + existingEntry.fileName());
                uploadPictures("/"+SavedProperties.selectedAddress + "/");
            }
        } 
        catch (DropboxException  e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Folder does not exist..." + e.fillInStackTrace());
            try 
            {
                Entry createFolder = mApi.createFolder("/"+SavedProperties.selectedAddress);
                Log.d(TAG,"Folder created..." + createFolder.rev);
                uploadPictures("/"+SavedProperties.selectedAddress + "/");
            } 
            catch (DropboxException e1)
            {
                 Log.d(TAG,"Create Folder DropboxException : " + e1.fillInStackTrace() );
            }       
        }
    }

    private void uploadPictures(String uploadTo) 
    {
        // Uploading Pictures....
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try 
        {
            for(int i =0 ; i < selectedImages.length; i++)
            {
                if(selectedImages[i]==0)
                {
                    String path = PictureGallery.images.get(i).toString().replace("file://", "");
                    String filename = PictureGallery.images.get(i).toString().split("/")[PictureGallery.images.get(i).toString().split("/").length-1];
                    File file = new File(path);
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    Entry newEntry = mApi.putFile(uploadTo + filename, inputStream, file.length(), null, null);
                    Log.i(TAG, "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
                    //Log.d(TAG,"PictureGallery " + PictureGallery.images.get(i).toString().split("/")[PictureGallery.images.get(i).toString().split("/").length-1]);
                }
            }
            progress.dismiss();
        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
            Log.e(TAG, "User has unlinked.");
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong while uploading.");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "File not found.");
        } 
        finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
```

i have used android sdk 1.3.1 in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems, and find it out. After access is done, create a new Entry as described above, but
set the parameter "boolean list" to true. If you had done this,List will not be null, and You can get 
the information you want with a for-loop

```
AccessTokenPair access = getStoredKeys();
mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(access);

try {
    // ----SET boolean list PARAMETER TO TRUE---------

    Entry dropboxDir = mDBApi.metadata("/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/", 0, null, true, null);
    if (dropboxDir.isDir) {
        List<Entry> contents = dropboxDir.contents;
        if (contents != null) {
            // ------CREATE NEW ENTRY AND THEN, GET THE FILENAME OF
            // EVERY FILE
            for (int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++) {
                Entry e = contents.get(i);
                String a = e.fileName();
                Log.d("dropbox", "FileName:" + a);
            }
        }
    }
    // ONLY A TEST CATCH, PLEASE DO WRIGHT EXCEPTION HANDLING HERE
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d("dropbox", "ERROR");
}
```

Comment: Entry dropboxDir = mDBApi.metadata("/", 1000, null, true, null); .......I'm using it like this to retrive all files and folders list, but getting exception...unablle to deliver result to activity

Comment: hello pratit-systematix...you should make a new question as this here could be outdated. Since this answer, there are about 4 years gone and the dropbox api is updated. Also, without seeing a error stacktrace, it´s hard to say what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Thanks.....posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961423/get-all-files-and-folders-list-with-dropbox-core-api-for-android

Answer (score 0):

```
Entry entries = mApi.metadata(Path, 100, null, true, null);

for (Entry e : entries.contents) {
    if (!e.isDeleted) {
        Log.i("Is Folder",String.valueOf(e.isDir));
        Log.i("Item Name",e.fileName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all FILES and FOLDER from path, then use this code, it will help you.

I got solution by myself.

```
    String mPath="/";  //You can change the path here to specific FOLDER
Entry dirent = null;
 try 
   {
      dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);            
    } 
 catch (DropboxException e)
   {
     System.out.println("Error Detail "+e.getMessage());
   }
```

> //Perform a Loop and retrieve all FILES and FOLDER from the PATH

```
     for (Entry ent: dirent.contents)
     {
       String name = ent.fileName();                           
       System.out.println("My File in Folder "+name);                        
      }
```