# Get all files and folders list with Dropbox Core API for Android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I want my app user to be able to view Dropbox files and folders, so that he/she can choose one of them and use in my app.

For this I used Dropbox Core API like this:

```
private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi;

    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(Constants.DROPBOX_APP_KEY, Constants.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
    mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
```

On my button click, I started authorization:

```
    mDBApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this);
```

and handled this in onResume(), like this

```
    if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
            mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

            String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();

            storeAccessToken(accessToken);
            setLoggedIn(true);

            Log.v("DbAuthLog", "DB Authentication successful");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
        }
    }
```

where setLoggedIn() is:

```
    private void setLoggedIn(boolean isLoggedIn) {
    AccessTokenPair access = new AccessTokenPair(Constants.DROPBOX_APP_KEY, Constants.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET);
    mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(access);

    if (isLoggedIn) {
        String[] fnames = null;
        DropboxAPI.DeltaPage<DropboxAPI.Entry> dirent = null;
        try {
            dirent = mDBApi.delta("");
            //dirent = mDBApi.metadata("/", 100, null, true, null);

            ArrayList<DropboxAPI.DeltaEntry<DropboxAPI.Entry>> files = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> dir=new ArrayList<String>();
            int i = 0;
            for (DropboxAPI.DeltaEntry<DropboxAPI.Entry> ent: dirent.entries)
            {
                files.add(ent);// Add it to the list of thumbs we can choose from
                //dir = new ArrayList<String>();
                dir.add(new String(files.get(i++).lcPath));
            }
            i=0;
            fnames=dir.toArray(new String[dir.size()]);
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But this throws exception, saying 'Failure delivering result to activity'.

Please suggest, I need a list of all files and folders.

Logcat:

```
W/DefaultRequestDirector: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=Www-Authenticate: OAuth realm="https://api.dropbox.com/"}

W/System.err: com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException
at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.parseAsJSON(RESTUtility.java:263)
at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:415)
at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:339)
at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.streamRequest(RESTUtility.java:194)
at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.request(RESTUtility.java:124)
at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.delta(DropboxAPI.java:2476)
at   com.example.admin.cloudintegrationsample.MainActivity$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:130)
at com.example.admin.cloudintegrationsample.MainActivity$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:125)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-22 13:23:50.194 14336-15079/com.example.admin.cloudintegrationsample  W/IdleConnectionHandler: Removing a connection that never existed!
```

Comment: please post the logcat, because one error could be caused by another. So we nee to see the full stacktrace.

Comment: I guess you are trying to access some DropBox methods which are not ready yet. What are you doing after `startOAuth2Authentication()` ? Is there any method call related to dropbox, directly after auth? You´ll have to wairt until authentication is complete, so everything you are doing after that, must be called in onResume() if auth was successfull, or if necessary in another place, be sure you are authenticated before executing the method.

Comment: After startOAuth2Authentication(), I wait for onResume to be called, and there on, I call for drop box methods.

Comment: UnlinkedException means not authentaicated. Can you describe what happens on the device? Is the DropBox Actvity open and ready to authenticate? Do you need to input your user data or does it work automatically?

Comment: Ya right, but now it's working. I don't know how. With the same code.

Comment: ahhh, I guess I know why. When do you have registrated at dropBox and when did you get the auth key? Because it needs up to 24 hours (sometimes a little bit longer) until it´s active.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs That's most certainly not true. Where did you see that?

Comment: for sure it is. I don´t say that it´s allways the case. But it´s my own experience long time ago as I integrated dropbox. Maybe I should write my comment like *It´s POSSIBLE that...*

Comment: No, that can't be the reason, because I created app on dropbox a few hrs ago.

Comment: But, I still have a question, I got this working using /delta....but it returns me all the files on dropbox. I tried using meta deta where I can specify, no. of files to be fetched, but didn't work. How can I do that?